# Using algebra and calculus i need to solve this written question for x

Tags: calculus

City a is separated by a 2km wide river and are located as shown in Figure 1 (not drawn to scale). A road is to be built between city A to B that crosses a bridge straight across the river.

Use the Sign Test to determine the type of stationary point

Test to see if you have a minimum

Answer (score 1):

Move $B$ $2$km closer to the river, in a direction perpendicular to the river, and ignore the river.  Then you won't even need to use calculus.

Specifically, the shortest distance between $A$ and$B$ is now the straight line distance
$$\sqrt{17^2+12^2}=\sqrt{433}$$
and the value of $x$ will be given by similar triangles:
$$x=17\times\frac{9}{12}=\frac{51}{4}\ .$$
Moving $B$ back where it was adds the $2$ km length of the bridge for a total of $2+\sqrt{433}$ km.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do with algebra, $A$ being defined as the origin, let us define two points $C(x,9)$ and $D(x,11)$. So, the distance between $A$ and $C$ is given by $$d_{AC}=\sqrt {(x-0)^2+(9-0)^2}=\sqrt {x^2+81}$$ The distance between $D$ and $B$ is given by $$d_{DB}=\sqrt {(17-x)^2+(14-11)^2}=\sqrt {x^2-34x+298}$$ So taking into account the fact tht $d_{CD}=2$, the total distance from $A$ to $B$ is $$d_{AB}=\sqrt {x^2+81}+2+\sqrt {x^2-34x+298}$$ what we want to be minimum. So, compute the derivative (it will contain radicals to be removed by proper rearrangement and squaring; this will finally let you with a quadratic equation $$-72 x^2+2754 x-23409=0$$ the roots of which being $x=\frac{51}{4}$ and $x=\frac{51}{2}$. The latest must be discarded since larger than $17$. So, the solution is $x=\frac{51}{4}$; for this value of $x$, the distance between $A$ and $B$ is then $2+\sqrt{433}=22.81$ km.

Computing the second derivative at  $x=\frac{51}{4}$ gives a value of $\frac{768}{433 \sqrt{433}}$ which is positive, then the solution corresponds to a minimum.

If you look at the variation of $d_{AB}$ as a function of $x$, you should notice that the largest distance would correspond to $x=0$ for which $d_{AB}=11+\sqrt{298}=28.26$ km.

You could also notice that, flying, the shortest distance batween $A$ and $B$ is $\sqrt {485} =22.02$ km.